# definition of norm and its positivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given a vector space $V$ over a subfield $F$ of the complex numbers, a norm on $V$ is a function $\| . \|: V \to R$ with the following properties:
For all $a \in F$ and all $ u, v \in V$,

(i)$\|av \| = |a|\|v\ $.
(ii)$\|u + v\| \le \|u\|+ \|v\|$.
(iii)$\|v\| \ge 0$ .
(iv)If $\|v\| = 0$ then $v=0$ is the zero vector.

But using (i) , (ii) and the properties of vector space we can have,

$||0||=||v+ (-v)|| \le ||v||+||-v|| =2||v||$ which implies $||v||\ge 0$. So why we write (iii)).

Comment: You are correct that the third property is redundant, but it is useful to write for clarity.

Comment: And we are done. ;-)

Comment: The point (iii) is not needed, as an example see the [gernam version](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normierter_Raum#Definition) on wikipedia (even if you don't speak german you should be able to understand it)

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Comment: iv) is *if and only if*. But the *only if* part is obvious. Anyway...